# Reuse links in a post across different languages

Tags: links, multi-language, plugin-wpml

I have posts in two languages, managed by WPML.

In one post, I share multiple links which are updated in a regular basis. Updating the same links for both languages is not an option (for now I only added this post in one language).

Which is the best way to define links text and URL only once, and reuse them in both languages?

I could code a shortcode and manage the links by code, but I would like to know if there is any plugin or other approach to accomplish this (I already did my research with no luck).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by using this plugin:

[**Global Content Blocks**](https://wordpress.org/plugins/global-content-blocks/)

I defined the links in `Content Blocks`. Then, all languages have the same shortcode pointing to a block. So, I only need to update the `Content Block` and the update propagates to all languages.

Answer (score 0):

Try WPML [Sticky Links](https://wpml.org/documentation/getting-started-guide/sticky-links/) module. It does exactly what you need.

Comment: I already use it. Sticky Links only works for internal links, the links I refer to are from external domains.

Comment: So practically you want to partially duplicate post content. (only links) Since post duplication works only one entire post content.

Comment: Yes, the plugin I mention in the other answer is really powerful. I'm currently using it for more than just links :)